# My cURL request confuses some servers?

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a cURL post request with the following script which posts to a form processing script:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/process_script.php";
$referer = "http://www.example.com";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11";
$postdata = array('message' => 'Hello, World!', 'name' => 'Bob');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_exec($ch);
```

It works fine on some urls.  Also, when I post it to my test script (which just outputs the referer and agent and postdata) it works just fine.

Some servers however give me this bizarre "The server could not understand your query" error though.  It's not a 403, because when I remove the user agent option, I do get a 403.  Is there something wrong with the user agent string?  It's pulled directly from my actual browser.

Are there more options I need to set to emulate a real browser?

Comment: If you indeed quoted the message as it is, it's an internal error of server. I'd suggest checking your params first: perhaps they should be named in uppercase or something. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but give this a try instead:

```
$postdata = array('message' => 'Hello, World!', 'name' => 'Bob');
$postdata = http_build_query($postdata);
```

The reason for doing this is because if you post the form using the url-encoded string returned by [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) the form is posted using  the enctype `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  When you use an array, it results in `multipart/form-data`.

It may be that some forms are expecting `urlencoded` data and do not understand (or decline to process) forms send in `multipart/form-data` encoding.

About `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like
>   ***'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'*** or as an array with the field name as key
>   and field data as value. If value is an array, the ***Content-Type*** header
>   will be set to ***multipart/form-data***.
>   *Source:* [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/curl_setopt)

Comment: Excellent, I always go with a urlencoded string unless I need to post a file or something; then using an array is easier.  Glad that was it.