# PHP cURL POST returns a 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: php, post, curl, jboss

I've got a simple PHP script that sends an HTTP POST request via cURL, and expects a json string in response (would have loved to use an existing library like pecl_http/HTTPRequest for this, but can't). The call consistently fails with a 415 error - Unsupported Media Type.  I think I'm not configuring cURL correctly, but after much searching, I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.  Here's some code:

```
class URLRequest
{
    public $url;
    public $headers;
    public $params;
    public $body;
    public $expectedFormat;
    public $method;

    public function URLRequest($aUrl, array $aHeaders, array $aParams, $aFormat = "json", $isPost = false, $aBody = "+")
    {
        $this->url = $aUrl;
        $this->headers = $aHeaders;
        $this->params = $aParams;
        $this->expectedFormat = $aFormat;
        $this->method = ($isPost ? "POST" : "GET");
        $this->body = $aBody;

    }

    public function exec()
    {

        $queryStr = "?";
        foreach($this->params as $key=>$val)
            $queryStr .= $key . "=" . $val . "&";

        //trim the last '&'
        $queryStr = rtrim($queryStr, "&");

        $url = $this->url . $queryStr;

        $request = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        if($this->method == "POST")
        {
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->body);

            //this prevents an additions code 100 from getting returned
            //found it in some forum - seems kind of hacky
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:"));
        }

        $response = curl_exec($request);
        curl_close($request);

        preg_match("%(?<=HTTP/[0-9]\.[0-9] )[0-9]+%", $response, $code);

        $resp = "";
        if($this->expectedFormat == "json")
        {
            //parse response
        }
        elseif($this->expectedFormat == "xml")
        {
            //parse response
        }

        return $resp;

    }
}


$url = "http://mydomain.com/myrestcall";

$query = array( "arg_1" =>      "test001",
                "arg_2" =>      "test002",
                "arg_3" =>      "test003");

$headers = array(    "Accept-Encoding" =>    "gzip",
                    "Content-Type" =>       "application/json",
                    "Accept" =>             "application/json",
                    "custom_header_1" =>    "test011",
                    "custom_header_2" =>    "test012",
                    "custom_header_3" =>    "test013");

$body = array(  "body_arg_1" =>      "test021",
                "body_arg_2" =>     array("test022", "test023"), 
                "body_arg_3" =>     "test024"); 


$request = new URLRequest($url, $headers, $query, "json", true, $body);

$response = $request->exec();
```

...and the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1047
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 16:30:44 GMT

<html><head><title>JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA - Error report</title></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - </h1><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().</u></p><h3>JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA</h3></body></html>
```

Any insights or ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may try to add an `Accept` header with `application/json`

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but no love :( Your comment reminded me that I should point out the some similar headers specifically in the example though, so thanks :)

Comment: Is the webservice you're trying to request a public or private API? You may be missing some parameters however, the response error is very generic and we may not be able to help if it is a private API.

Comment: Private, unfortunately.  I know that this severely limits the degree to which others can help troubleshoot this issue, but them's the breaks I'm afraid.  Mostly I'm hoping someone more experienced with php or curl will spot some common pitfall that I've walked into.

Comment: Do you have any other way to test your webservice? Before to take much time debugging your code which looks fairly simple and correct, be sure that the remote service is not broken.

Comment: I think it's the way I'm doing the cURL POST.  I just tried doing the post using Poster (Chrome plugin) and it was successful.  I think I'm going to Wireshark it and see if the Poster call and my call match up. When I find the error I'll post it here for sure.

Comment: No need to use Wireshark, just take a look at the header Request in both your chrome extension and your php script.

Comment: there are several things wrong with your code (like incorrectly encoding the query string, it should be ```$queryStr .= urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($val) . "&";``` (or even better: ```$queryStr=http_build_query($this->params);```) and using regex to parse response code instead of using CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, it should just be ```$code=curl_getinfo($request,CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);```), but without the API documentation for mydomain.com/myrestcall, nobody here knows what your request is supposed to look like, we need documentation for your api endpoint before we can be of any help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Problem solved! Here's the issue:

Sending an associative-array of headers DOES NOT WORK with cURL. There are several forums scattered around that show examples using an associative array for headers. DON'T DO IT!

The *correct* way (which is also scattered around the internets, but that I'm too dense to have noticed) is to construct your header key/value pairs as strings, and pass a standard array of these strings when setting the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option.

So in summary,

**WRONG:**

```
$headers = array(    "Accept-Encoding" =>    "gzip",
                     "Content-Type" =>       "application/json",
                     "custom_header_1" =>    "test011",
                     "custom_header_2" =>    "test012",
                     "custom_header_3" =>    "test013");
```

**RIGHT:**

```
$headers = array(    "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
                     "Content-Type: application/json",
                     "custom_header_1: test011",
                     "custom_header_2: test012",
                     "custom_header_3: test013");
```

I hope this comes in handy to some other noble doofus down the road before they waste as much time debugging as I did.

If I had to guess, I would assume that the same rule applies to the POST body key/value pairs as well, which is why @drew010 's comment about using `http_build_query()` or `json_encode()` to stringify your message body is a great idea as well.

Thanks to everyone for your very useful comments, and for you time and consideration.  In the end, a side by side comparison of the http traffic (captured via Wireshark) revealed the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Damn! I was trying EVERYTHING and literally found dozens of different pages and tutorials showing how to set headers with key=>value and it simply wasn't working!
THANKS, IAN!

Comment: Thanks for saving possible hours/days of frustration mate :)

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem is that you are passing an array as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.  By passing an array, this forces the `POST` request to use `multipart/form-data` when the server is probably expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Try changing

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->body);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->body));
```

See [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) for more information and also this answer: [My cURL request confuses some servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559662/my-curl-request-confuses-some-servers/9559752#9559752)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - same response though.  I'll keep this in mind moving forward though. You make a good point.

Comment: Sniffing the entire request in Wireshark may be helpful so you can see the HTTP request and response.  Are they expecting you to post JSON data rather than urlencoded data?

Comment: It is expecting JSON, and per my response to Boris' comment, I'm going to follow your council, Wireshark my call along with the call sent from Poster, and compare the two.

Comment: In that case you may need to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to `json_encode($this->body)` and confirm that the content-type header going out is not being overridden by curl back to anything other than `application/json`

Comment: Checking out what wireshark has to say on the matter - thought I had it, and made this comment, then had to edit it to remove erroneous findings...

Comment: Can you confirm that the `if ($this->method == 'POST')` block is being entered?  Also, when you set the `Expect` header in the post block, you are clearing all the headers that were previously set.  Even so, I don't think that should revert the request back to GET though.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
 $data ="data";

 $headers = [
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff",
                "Accept:application/json",
                "Cache-Control:no-cache"
            ];

  $auth =  $USER . ":" . $PASSWORD;


 $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $auth);  
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

         $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed changing the header.

My code:

```
$authorization = 'authorization: Bearer '.trim($apiKey);
$header = [
'Content-Type: application/json',
$authorization
];
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

I don't know why the array function doesn't work :

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
application/json',
$authorization));
```