# Lightspeed API with PHP Curl

Tags: php, api, curl, error-handling

I want to perform a post call with the use of an api.
But after some changes I still get the same error and it doesn't get solved/

This is the code I use:

```
 // init
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/registration/register');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// array fields var
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'city' => 'Gent',
        'company' => 'cedric resto',
        'email' => 'cedric@tills.be',
        'firstName' => 'Cedric',
        'lastName' => 'De Weirt',
        'locale' => 'Gent',
        'number' => '33',
        'password' => '1234',
        'phone' => '0476612438',
        'referer' => '13c435f9-084a-4e79-866f-8b9800e5c14f',
        'street' => 'Testlaan',
        'zip'=> '9000')));

// receive server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $server_output;

// further processing
if (strpos($server_output,'201') == true)
{
    // created
    echo 'Created';
}
else
{
    // catch the error(s)
    echo 'Error Catch';
}
```

I constanly get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 415

Problem accessing /PosServer/rest/registration/register. Reason:

    Unsupported Media Type
Powered by Jetty://
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL POST returns a 415 - Unsupported Media Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087872/php-curl-post-returns-a-415-unsupported-media-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't telling the server what format you are sending, and it's not valid.

You need to `json_encode` the array:

```
$payload = json_encode(array(
        'city' => 'Gent',
        'company' => 'cedric resto',
        'email' => 'cedric@tills.be',
        'firstName' => 'Cedric',
        'lastName' => 'De Weirt',
        'locale' => 'Gent',
        'number' => '33',
        'password' => '1234',
        'phone' => '0476612438',
        'referer' => '13c435f9-084a-4e79-866f-8b9800e5c14f',
        'street' => 'Testlaan',
        'zip'=> '9000'));
```

Remove `http_build_query` it's not necessary:

```
// array fields var
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

Send the header type of the data you are sending:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

The end result is:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/registration/register');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$payload = json_encode(array(
        'city' => 'Gent',
        'company' => 'cedric resto',
        'email' => 'cedric@tills.be',
        'firstName' => 'Cedric',
        'lastName' => 'De Weirt',
        'locale' => 'Gent',
        'number' => '33',
        'password' => '1234',
        'phone' => '0476612438',
        'referer' => '13c435f9-084a-4e79-866f-8b9800e5c14f',
        'street' => 'Testlaan',
        'zip'=> '9000'));

// array fields var
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

// receive server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $server_output;

// further processing
if (strpos($server_output,'201') == true)
{
    // created
    echo 'Created';
}
else
{
    // catch the error(s)
    echo 'Error Catch';
}
```

Also, it appears you are missing a field that you'll need to add into your array:

```
{"code":"1401","description":"Registration failed, no valid country in company"}
```

That's unrelated; the (HTTP ERROR 415) should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks!
It is working.
I've added all the requested variables that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

So far I know it is expecting json object as post data. So do these two.

Add json header

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

And now change your `http_build_query` with the function `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please encode array containing request parameters into json format using json_encode function instead of http_build_query() and also you need to define content-type header as application/json in HTTP request header since format of payload is in json format.

```
// init
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/registration/register');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// array fields var
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
        'city' => 'Gent',
        'company' => 'cedric resto',
        'email' => 'cedric@tills.be',
        'firstName' => 'Cedric',
        'lastName' => 'De Weirt',
        'locale' => 'Gent',
        'number' => '33',
        'password' => '1234',
        'phone' => '0476612438',
        'referer' => '13c435f9-084a-4e79-866f-8b9800e5c14f',
        'street' => 'Testlaan',
        'zip'=> '9000')));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
// receive server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $server_output;

// further processing
if (strpos($server_output,'201') == true)
{
    // created
    echo 'Created';
}
else
{
    // catch the error(s)
    echo 'Error Catch';
}
```