# PHP cURL POST: 415 Unsupported Media with j, 400 Bad Request without

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a problem trying to pass information with a POST method through cURL in PHP.

My "train.php" file has the following:

```
<?php

$tfile = $_FILES["newtrain"];
$filepath = $tfile['tmp_name'];

$fields = array(
  "training_metadata" => '{\\"language\\":\\"pt\\",\\"name\\":\\"TestClassifier\\"}',
  "training_data" => '@'.$filepath
);

$params = http_build_query($fields);

$tSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_URL,"myURL.com");
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$train=curl_exec($tSession);

if($errno = curl_errno($tSession)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}

print_r($train);

curl_close($tSession);
?>
```

The equivalent when I send the cURL command from the terminal is the following (or rather, my PHP is supposed to mimic this):

```
curl -i --user "user":"password" -F training_data=@/Users/PT020555/file.csv -F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"pt\",\"name\":\"TestClassifier\"}" "myURL.com"
```

I searched and I'm not supposed to get the 415 using `http_build_query()` (and apparently actually solves it?), so I'm not sure where the problem is.

I also tried to pass the `$fields` array straight into `curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);`, and in this case I get a 400 Bad Request:

{ "code" : 400, "error" : "Missing metadata", "description" : "The required training metadata is missing. The request should contain 'language' and 'name' besides the training data." }

I also tried writing the `$fields` array in the following format according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087872/php-curl-post-returns-a-415-unsupported-media-type), but I'm unsure whether I should `urlencode()`, where, and if I have to try to escape characters:

```
$fields = array(
  "training_metadata: '{\\\"language\\\":\\\"pt\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"TestClassifier\\\"}'",
  "training_data: @$filepath"
);
```

In the previous case, I also get a 400 Bad Request, and if I apply `http_build_query()` I get 415 again.

The file comes from this HTML - I pick up the file.csv from here:

```
<FORM id = "formtr" NAME = "formtr" METHOD = "POST" action = "curl_train.php" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="newtrain">Data for training</label>
 <input id="newtrain" name="newtrain" type="file" required>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" id='train' name = 'train' VALUE = "Train new"> </form>
```

I'm on Mac, if relevant.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: 1. You need a header `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` 2. Why the backslashes in your `$fields` array?

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Comment: Hi, I added `curl_setopt($tSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));` and get 200 requests now (sometimes a 500, though, but one thing at a time). Since I'm in PHP 5.6 and following b3n's answer, I changed `"training_data" => '@'.$filepath`to `"training_data" => new \CURLFile($filepath)`. There's still something missing as I don't get the expected behaviour from the URL. When I make the command I terminal I get also a json with the status of the API I'm injecting files to, but not in the webpage.

I also removed the double backslash in `$fields`, no need.