# I am getting a strange parameter error with a POST request

Tags: php, curl, post

So this is the error that i am getting when trying to make a POST request to the streamlabs api. I have put the pastebin to the gode below.

Im most likely being so dumb. Thanks

Edit: Even with $code = $_GET['code']; It still returns the same error. I'm unsure as to why. Could it be on the receiver's api having a problem? Im new to php and POST / GET calls. Normally i make them via Ajax but it always returns a CORS error because they are forcing the use php for security. Its only for personal use and won't be used by anyone else.

Solution:
I am unsure how to use stack overflow effectively so i apologise in advance but the solution was in Drew010's comment!

The code:

```
<?php 

$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client_id = 'Removed For Security'; // Your client id
$client_secret = 'Removed For Security'; // Your secret
$redirect_uri = "http://simpservers.co.uk/supporters/"; // Your redirect uri

$url = 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token';

# Our new data
$data = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri, 'code' => strval($code));
# Create a connection
$url = 'https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token';

//initialize cURL
$handle = curl_init($url);

//post values
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//set to return the response
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute
$response = (curl_exec( $handle ));

print_r($data);

echo $response;
```

Data:

```
(
    [grant_type] => authorization_code
    [client_id] => Removed For Security
    [client_secret] => Removed For Security
    [redirect_uri] => http://simpservers.co.uk/supporters/
    [code] => 4M8WUq97OzeBgL3O41tmVEb4dY9HAy3zdeRQWFFg
)

The response:

    {
        "error":"invalid_request",
        "error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"code\" parameter."
    }
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Do not just dump your code onto external platforms; the minimum of code to reproduce your problem, needs to be included directly into your question. (In text form, and properly formatted.)

Comment: `$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);` sounds like a good way to mess up that value. This value _is not_ a URL, so why do you treat it that way?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088192/892493 Try changing `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` to `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`