# Hello, I did a study with Php curl, the response is not responding as I want. Where is the problem?

Tags: php, curl, python-requests, request

I did a study with Php curl, the response is not responding as I want. Where is the problem please help.

**Response:**

```
Array ( [timestamp] => 1611484830616 [status] => 415 [error] => Unsupported Media Type [exception] => org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException [message] => Unsupported Media Type [path] => /squat/getSquatMarketingProduct )
```

**Php code:**

```
$post = array(
    'clientKey' => 'AC491770-B16A-4273-9CE7-CA790F63365E',
    'clientVersion' => '13.0.1',
    'language' => 'tr',
    'operatingSystem' => 'android'
);

$headers = array(

    'Content-Type'=> 'application/json',
    'Host' =>  'm.vodafone.com.tr',
    'Connection' =>  'Keep-Alive',
    'Accept-Encoding' =>  'gzip',
    'User-Agent' =>  'okhttp/3.14.1'
);

$cs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/api?sid=".$token);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($cs);

$jsons = json_decode($output, true);
print_r($jsons);
curl_close ($cs);
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087872/php-curl-post-returns-a-415-unsupported-media-type help?

Comment: @nigel-ren I tried this time I got the Bad Requests error.

Comment: Well... you'll have to handle the unextecpted response properly... like in life: you not always get to hear what you wanted - deal with it!

Comment: @lars-stegelitz I've been trying to figure it out for about 2 hours and still can't figure it out :(

Comment: Ask the provider of the service what the message means...